# Enviar somente objeto da lista que houve alteração para o controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, razor, lista

Possuo uma `view` que lista todos os meus **clientes**. Cada cliente possui 3 `checkbox` onde o usuário seleciona os mesmos, e envia para o `controller` - através do botão (submit) - os dados para alterar.
O método está funcionando perfeitamente. Porém, ao enviar, ele envia todos os clientes, até os que não tiveram alteração. Assim ele atualiza todos (até mesmo os que não foram modificados). Isso não me causa problemas, mas provoca uma demora (já que ele tem que percorrer toda a lista para alterar).

Gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de verificar se o cliente foi modificado, e enviar somente os que foram ao meu `controller`.

Minha `View` está dessa forma:

```
@using PrestacaoWeb.UI.Helpers
@model List<PrestacaoWeb.Application.ViewModels.ClientePrestacaoViewModel>

@using (Html.BeginForm("EditarMes", "Cliente", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Salvar"/>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th> Cliente </th>
        <th> 1 </th>
        <th> 2 </th>
        <th> 3 </th>
        <th> Cidade </th>
        <th> Responsável </th>
        <th> Obs </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tbody>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
            <tr>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].ClienteId)
                <td style="width: 100px">
                    <p align="center">@Model[i].NomeCliente</p>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 20px"><p align="center"> <b>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model[i].EnvioPrestacao.bJaneiro)</b> </p> </td>

                <td style="width: 20px"><p align="center"> <b>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model[i].EnvioPrestacao.bFevereiro)</b> </p> </td>

                <td style="width: 20px"><p align="center"> <b>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model[i].EnvioPrestacao.bMarco)</b> </p> </td>
                 <td>
                    @Model[i].Cliente.Cidade.Nome
                </td>

                <td style="width: 100px">
                    <p align="center">@Model[i].Responsavel</p>
                </td>
                    <td style="width: 210px">
                        <p align="center">@Model[i].Observacao.</p>
                    </td>

            </tr>

        }
        </tbody>
</table>
}
```

Ao clicar no botão **Salvar**, ele envia todos os objetos da lista para o método **EditarMes**, em meu `Controller`.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult EditarMes(IList<ClientePrestacaoViewModel> prestacaoViewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View("Index");
    foreach (var item in prestacaoViewModel.Where(item => item != null))
    {
        _clienteContext.Atualizar(item);
        TempData["MensagemSuccess"] = "Cliente alterado com sucesso!";

    }
    return Redirect(ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
}
```

Se eu alterar todos os clientes, está certo, irá demorar mesmo. Agora, caso altere somente um cliente, e ele envie 30 para o `controller`, não seria "legal" esperar por isso.

Comment: Você poderia implementar um Model Binder customizado (implementação de IModelBinder) que fizesse o binding apenas dos elementos modificados. Isto não faria com que o post ficasse menor mas dispensaria o foreach dentro do controller.

Comment: @rcompanhoni Você teria algum exemplo de uma implementação qualquer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É mais barato em custo de processamento trazer a lista original e comparar os valores.

Aparentemente você usa um repositório, então não sei como isso é feito, mas usando um contexto do Entity Framework seria algo assim:

```
var listaOriginal = contexto.ClientePrestacoes.AsNoTracking().Where(/* Condição */).ToList();

foreach (var item in prestacaoViewModel.Where(item => item != null))
{
    var itemOriginal = listaOriginal.Single(l => l.Id == item.Id);
    if (item.bJaneiro != itemOriginal.bJaneiro || item.bFevereiro != itemOriginal.bFevereiro || item.bMarco != itemOriginal.bMarco) {
        _clienteContext.Atualizar(item);
    }

    TempData["MensagemSuccess"] = "Cliente alterado com sucesso!";
}
```

Aproveitando, isto não é uma boa prática:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View("Index");
```

Neste comando, você deixa de implementar o comportamento padrão do MVC, que é devolver a mesma tela em caso de invalidade de alguma informação em tela, e não carrega qualquer dado que sirva para o preenchimento da tela.

Comment: Você por acaso conhece alguma maneira de selecionar apenas alguns dos itens da coleção para serem enviados para a Action do OP, acho que essa seria uma boa alternativa e que iria ser menos custosa em termos de processamento para o servidor.

Comment: @Zignd Na verdade "selecionar" quais dados vão para o *Controller* no `POST` não faz muito sentido. Ou o dado foi escrito na tela, ou não foi. De qualquer forma, o *Controller* precisa conferir todos os registros pra entender o que foi alterado e o que não foi.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez eu achava que seria mais "Custoso", pois tenho que buscar os dados e comparar. Mas como não é, vou fazer as alterações. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Haa... Sobre o `return`, é que estou trabalhando com uma janela **Modal**, então faço retornar para a `View` anterior.